# Android : Access elements in ListView populated with BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I am working on an Android project in which I am currently working on chat functionality. Now, whenever an user sends a message, it is added in the ListView, which is populated by BaseAdapter. A new message is added by `baseAdapterObject.add(item);`.

Now, whenever an user sends a message, I am adding it directly to the already existing List and then waiting for a reply from the server confirming the message was delivered. For the first step, I would like to show a Gray checkmark, and for 2nd message received from server, I would like to show Blue checkmark.

**Unfortunately, I don't know how to access the already populated list and change the background image of an ImageView.** . Each message has a random-number, with which I can compare for which message I received confirmation.

Code :

```
public void recieveUpdatedMessageFromServer(String channelName, Map<String, Object> input){
        String randomNumberFromServer = ((Map) input.get("data")).get("random").toString();
        if (randomNumberFromServer.equals(randomNos)) {
            messageRecieved = true;
            randomNos = "";
        }
  chatMessagesAdapter.add(insertMap);
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        chatMessagesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                });

  public class ChatMessagesAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


        private Activity activity = null;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;

        public ChatMessagesAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
            activity = a;
            data = d;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        public void add(HashMap<String, String> item) {
            data.add(item);

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View vi = convertView;
            if (convertView == null)
                vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.chat_messages_row, parent, false);

            TextView chatText = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.chatText);
            ImageView userImage = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.chatImage);
            TextView firstName = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.personName);
            ImageView checkMark = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.checMarkChat);
            HashMap<String, String> chatList;
            chatList = data.get(position);

            chatText.setText(chatList.get(ChatMessagesActivity.chatText));
            checkMark.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.blue_icon);
            firstName.setText(chatList.get(ChatMessagesActivity.firstName));
            if (!(chatList.get(ChatMessagesActivity.chatImageId).equals("0"))) {
                Picasso.with(context).load(StaticRestTemplate.baseURL + "image/" + chatList.get(ChatMessagesActivity.chatImageId)).fit().into(userImage);
            }
            return vi;
        }
    }
}
```

chat_messages_row.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="2.5dip">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="125dp"
        android:id="@+id/frameLayout2">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/chatImage"
            android:layout_width="107dp"
            android:layout_height="107dp"
            android:padding="2dp" />

    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/chatText"
        android:layout_width="230dp"
        android:layout_height="76dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/frameLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:id="@+id/personName"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/chatText"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/chatText"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        />

    <ImageView
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/checMarkChat"
        android:background="@drawable/blue_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/personName"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/personName" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="Small Text"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="49dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="49dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="208dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope this much information is enuf. Kindly let me know if anything else required. Thank you. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a class object to help.

For example, you can **create a list of message objects:**

```
class Message {

     private String message;
     private boolean gray_tick;
     private boolean blue_tick;

     ....
 }
```

Change your hashmap in your BaseAdapter to take in the corresponding object.

```
 private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Message>> data;
```

From there, you can set your **BaseAdapter** to read these values and show the correct coloured ticks at the right time.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So, whenever I populate the list, I should populate this list differently or together? Each msg has an unique ID attached to it and is part of the List. How can I add the blue tick mark once I recieve confirmation about message?

Comment: if you have an unique ID attached to each message, I will suggest you to use HashMap<ID, Message> you can retrieve the Message from your HashMap and change the tick status and request for a notifyDatasetChanged to update your list.

Comment: This helps....I will try it out, and come back to you if I have any problems. Thank you.